# interpolation of coordinates in python

Tags: python, interpolation, heatmap

I want to interpolate "missing" points on a heatmap that right now looks like this:

[image: heatmap].

The csv file is simply a pair of coordinates on each line, separated by semicolons. For example, a single line looks like this:

```
0.2324;0.343434
```

The `interpolation="sinc"` is not changing anything, the plot looks exactly the same with or without it e.g.:

```
a = plt.imshow(img, extent=extent, origin='lower', cmap="jet", interpolation="sinc")
```

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import csv


x = []
y = []

plik_csv = "plik.csv"

with open(plik_csv, 'r') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in lines:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(-float(row[1]))


x_list=np.array(x)
y_list=np.array(y)

def myplot(x, y, s, bins=1000):
    heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)
    heatmap = gaussian_filter(heatmap, sigma=s)

    extent = [min(x_list), max(x_list), min(y_list), max(y_list)]
    return heatmap.T, extent


print("wykres")
sigma = 40
img, extent = myplot(x, y, sigma)
a = plt.imshow(img, extent=extent, origin='lower', cmap="jet", interpolation="sinc")
plt.xlim([-0.4,0.7])
plt.ylim([-0.4,0])
for pos in ['right', 'top', 'bottom', 'left']:
    plt.gca().spines[pos].set_visible(False)


plt.colorbar(a)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "missing points"?

Comment: I want to make it a "banana shape", as it is a photon path heatmap

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. You want to make *what* a "banana shape"? What points are missing?

Comment: This is a photon path simulation. The photon's coordination is saved in bigger steps than i want to view, as it is shown above. I want to interpolate the whole path not just the saved points.

Comment: This code is applying `np.histogram2d()` on the point data that you're reading in. That function will count how many points land in each bin. Sometimes that count is 0, because there are no points there. But from `plt.imshow()`'s perspective, those zeros are not missing data - they're zero, which is a valid value.

Comment: i know, that's why i thought interpolation could help with it

Comment: This sounds like a data science/statistics problem, more than a programming problem.

Comment: thought i could just simply use interpolation='sinc', or kriging or idw, just don't know how to apply it